# How do I increment a variable in PHP when an href link is clicked

Tags: php, html

I want $counter=$counter +1, when this link on my website is clicked:

```
<a href="?oldp=<?=$i+1?>"><img src="images/old.jpg" width="190" height="32" /></a>
```

I've tried `$counter++;` in several creative ways, none of which seem to have worked.

Comment: How about [*sessions*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) ?

Comment: What is `$i`? And how and where are you updating it?

Comment: PHP is server side, you're confused about the very basics. Read the first part of [this answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35758/xss-parsing-javascript/35761#35761) to get more insight ...

Comment: not without reloading the page.  is that a problem? if so you'd have to involve JS/jQuery and some AJAX

Comment: Where do you set `$counter`? If you want it to increment when a user navigates to a new page then you need to store `$counter` somewhere, i.e. in a cache, session, database etc.

Answer (score 2):

PHP is a **server-side** language.

This means that PHP is (most often) only responsible from

**When the server receives a request**

until

**The PHP program outputs the page**.

So if you want something to happen in response to your action AFTER the page is loaded (e.g. clicking a link), PHP cannot handle that.

Now, you should choose your implementation in either `Javascript` or `PHP` depending on what you want to achieve.

- If you want to store the counter value in your server, and increment it:

  - Set the destination of the link to the exactly same page as the one you are viewing now. Use `$_SESSION` to store a value, and it will be stored across multiple requests.
- If you want to see the value of the counter go up as you click on the link:

  - Use Javascript to store the counter as an variable, and increment it on each click. This will be reset if you refresh the page.

*Note: You cannot achieve neither of this if your link takes you to another page. That becomes a whole new story.*